# Unity3D gives version error when .blend file is placed in unity's assets folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

When I copy .blend file in Unity's Assets folder it says

> Blender could not convert the .blend file to FBX file.
>   You need to use Blender 2.45-2.49 or 2.58 and later versions for direct Blender import to work.
>   UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:ProjectWindowDrag(HierarchyProperty, Boolean)
>   UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

But I am currrently using version 2.7. I am using a .blend file from internet source to use in my game. Does re-saving help in getting rid of errors or is there another possible and efficent way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: "Does re-saving helps in getting rid of errors "  You should try it and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Although Unity has full function over .Blend files I belive downloading the .Blend file from the internet is the problem 
( You may test that theory by exporting a simple model of your own and see if it works with Unity )
If your test model works then it's obviously something wrong downloading it from the internet.
I've had problems with this before and to date have had no solution I suggest trying to copy the model and model it for your self ( perhaps even copy and paste it from one project file to another) 
One obvious sign that it will not export correctly is if editing your model in blender sends the model into a orange tint and the object would not be able to be edited....
In conclusion the best thing you can do if it's the internet to blame is attempt to recreat the model and/or animations :) hope it helps and good luck :)